# How to set ng command to hgrc file about mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

## Tool

Mercurial

---

I want to edit ~/.hgrc file to set ng command like this:

```
hg push -f
```

How to do?

Comment: Explain in more details what you want to do. It's not clear.

Comment: Do you want to be able to enter ng on the command line and have your 'hg push -f' execute?

Comment: you know what is it alias?
[alias](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/alias.1posix.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aliases you specify on .hgrc are internal for mercurial.

For example with this:

```
[alias]
ng = push -f
```

you can now type `hg ng`, this is an "inside" alias.

But, if you want a global alias (typing just `ng` and not `hg ng`) then you must put it in .bashrc (or .bash_aliases if already exists)

```
alias ng="hg push -f"
```

Comment: When I type **hg ng**,that equals **hg push -f**?So that's run **hg push -f** again?

Comment: @cho If you type `hg ng` and you wrote the alias in the hgrc then yes, is just a shortcut. One run of `hg ng` equals one run of `hg push -f`

Comment: But I want to ignore the command **hg push -f**,not short link.